# Injecting docker env variable to spring property with comma in it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I have a spring app that has property in application.yml like this:

```
url-pattern-regex-list: ${URL_PATTERN_REGEX_LIST}
```

When I manually inject this regex it works:

```
url-pattern-regex-list: ['(?i)(https?:\/\/)?[-a-z\p{L}A-Z0-9@:\.]{1,256}\.[-a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}]{2,20}[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+\.~"\*=\p{L}]*\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:()_\+\.~#?&"%\*\/=\p{L}]*']
```

But since this app is dockerized and I would like to pass the property through docker env variable, then docker splits string on comma values.
And result List is:

- ['(?i)(https?://)?[-a-z\p{L}A-Z0-9@:.]{1
- 256}.[-a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}]{2
- 20}[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%*+.~"*=\p{L}]*/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:()*+.~#?&"%*/=\p{L}]*']

How can I escape comma so that it is not parsed as new row, I tried using \ before comma but still same thing happens.

Here is docker env variable that I get running docker inspect:

```
"URL_PATTERN_REGEX_LIST=['(?i)(https?:\\/\\/)?[-a-z\\p{L}A-Z0-9@:\\.]{1,256}\\.[-a-zA-Z0-9\\p{L}]{2,20}[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+\\.~\"\\*=\\p{L}]*\\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:()_\\+\\.~#?&\"%\\*\\/=\\p{L}]*']"
```

Other way that works if I write manually to application.yml is like this, but not sure if it is possible to do that with docker env variables.

```
    url-pattern-regex-list:
        - '(?i)(https?:\/\/)?[-a-z\p{L}A-Z0-9@:\.]{1,256}\.[-a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}]{2,20}[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+\.~"\*=\p{L}]*\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:()_\+\.~#?&"%\*\/=\p{L}]*'
        - '(?i)(https?:\/\/)[-a-z\p{L}A-Z0-9@:\.]{1,256}\.[-a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}]{2,20}[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+\.~"\*=\p{L}]*'
```

Comment: That last line suggests you are only setting a single environment variable named `URL_PATTERN_REGEX_LIST`; Docker is not splitting it.  Could you use the standard Spring Boot environment-variable rules to set a variable `URLPATTERNREGEXLIST_0` perhaps?

Comment: It is supposed to be configurable. Here as an example I set only one field but it could be that there are multiple items in the list. So that would not work.

Comment: See for example [Binding From Environment Variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables) in the Spring Boot documentation; each list item would get its own environment variable.